# Using Imap - Mail encoding weirdness

Tags: python, email, encoding, python-3.x, imaplib

I'm using imap to retrieve mails from a server which works fine. I'm fetching the mails in RFC 822 like so:

```
r, data = mailserver.fetch(mailnr, '(RFC822)')
```

This gives me decipherable mails for the most part but now I have a multipart mail that looks like this:

> From :  xxx xxx
>
> To :  xxx xxx
>
> Subject : 
>   =?utf-8?Q?online_verf=C3=BCgbar_-_TESTQUELLE_f=C3=BCr_Regel?=     =?utf-8?Q?-_u_Benachrichtigungdienst_()?=
>
> Content-Type :  multipart/alternative;
>     boundary="----=_NextPart_457512452482695058637"
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding :  None
>
> MIME-Version :  1.0
>
> Payload:
>
> =20
>   =20 sourcename:TESTQUELLE f=C3=BCr Regel- u Benachrichtigungdienst;csi:123456= ;publishdate:05=2E11=2E2013

The mail appears to be utf-8 but somehow the text is also url-encoded or something like that.

It seem like url encoded only instead of "%" "=" is used.

Any ideas on how i get this to look like normal text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found this:

```
mail.get_payload(decode=1).decode('utf-8')
```

I've only used get_payload() which gave me that string.

Answer (score 1):

The data appears to be unicode text that has been encoded as UTF-8, and then encoded as quotable-printable. There is a module "`quopri`" to encode / decode this - http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/quopri.html.

If you use `quopri.decodestring` to decode to UTF-8, and then decode that to unicode, yuo should be able to read it.